# Mock Abstract Parent Method of Field

Tags: unit-testing, abstract-class, mockito, parent, legacy

**FIRSTLY: I am testing legacy code.**

**I am testing an abstract class we will call Class A.**

*Class A* has Field of type *Class B*. *Class B* is a child of Abstract base class we will call *B_Base*.

**MY PROBLEM:** In a method of class A, the instance of class B calls a method in *B_Base.*

I have tried mocking a B class and then replacing the Field with the mocked B Class, however, everytime it runs the parent method, there is a NullPointerException in the Mockito.when() method, meaning the parent B_Base class is NOT mocked.

Here is an idea of what the code looks like.

```
public abstract class A {     //this is the class Im testing.
      public B bInstance;

      public boolean methodIAmTesting {
           int hello = bInstance.method_Only_In_B_Base();
           ...
      }    
}
```

The test:

```
 public class TestClass extends A {
    //here is the constructor etc..

    @Test
    public void test1 {   
        TestClass x = new TestClass();
        bInstance = Mockito.mock(B.class);

        // ERROR IS HERE V
        Mockito.when(bInstance.method_Only_In_B_Base()).thenReturn(50);
        Assert.assertTrue(x.methodIAmTesting());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try doing `x.setBInstance(bInstance)` or something similar? You've mocked out a B.class, but it's not the same object as the field in your TestClass.

Comment: Is that right? Well that would explain a lot. There are no setters in the code, but what exactly sets the value as the mock? If you try to pass a non-mocked object to the verify method, it will throw an error and tell you to use a mock. I have tried this with bInstance and it does not throw that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [J L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772521/j-l) mentioned, you've actually got two instances kicking around, because your TestClass extends A.

What you have:

```
public class TestClass extends A {
  @Test public void test1() {
    Class TestClass x = new TestClass();
    bInstance = Mockito.mock(B.class);
    // ...
  }
}
```

What you want:

```
public class TestClass extends A {
  @Test public void test1 {
    Class TestClass x = new TestClass();
    x.bInstance = Mockito.mock(B.class);  // <-- replace bInstance on x
    // ...
  }
}
```

JUnit creates an instance of your test class automatically, so when you call `x = new TestClass()` you're creating *a separate instance for test*, and your call for `bInstance = mock(B.class)` is setting the mock on the instance that JUnit creates rather than the `x` instance you create.

Note that it's very unusual to have a JUnit test class subclass the system under test. Consider a design like this instead:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ATest {
  private static class TestClass extends A {
    // ...
  }

  @Test public void test1 {
    Class TestClass x = new TestClass();
    x.bInstance = Mockito.mock(B.class);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not final. But by default, does a Mockito mock of a child also mock the shared parent methods?

Comment: Ah! Figured it out. It's subtle, but basically there are two instances of `TestClass` kicking around--one you create in test1 and one that JUnit creates automatically for you.